# Issues comparing objects

Tags: java, compare

I am trying to remove a "thing" from an arraylist in one class, and add it to another arraylist in a different class.

I have a Player class that holds two array lists, which are of type Creature and type SpecialIncomeCounter.
I also have a Bag class that holds an array list of "Things", which are Creatures and SpecialIncomeCounters.

My Creature and SpecialIncomeCounter classes both inherit from my abstract class Thing.

In a third class, I am trying to take "Things" from my Bag array list and add it into the correct array list in my player class.

This is what I am doing now:

```
Thing thing;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    thing = bag.bag.get(i);
    if(thing == Creature){ //this doesn't work
        p1.addCreature((Creature)thing);
        bag.bag.remove(i);
    }
    else if(thing ==  SpecialIncomeCounter){  //this doesn't work
        p1.addSpecialIncomeCounter((SpecialIncomeCounter)thing);
        bag.bag.remove(i);
    }
}
```

The issue is I can't figure out how to tell if thing is of type SpecialIncomeCounter or Creature.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instanceof` is what you're looking for.

```
 Thing thing;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        thing = bag.bag.get(i);
        if(thing instanceof Creature){ 
            p1.addCreature((Creature)thing);
            bag.bag.remove(i);
        }
        else if(thing instanceof SpecialIncomeCounter){  
            p1.addSpecialIncomeCounter((SpecialIncomeCounter)thing);
            bag.bag.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I totally forgot about instanceof!